# how can I turn a hard coded slider with thumbnail into a dynamic one

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a slideshow with thumbnails hardcoded with html and using onclick events with javascript to control the slideshow previous and next button and the thumbnail clicks. I turned the content dynamically for wordpress, however, I cannot make work the thumbnail onclick events as the currentSlide(n) is hardcoded. How can I do to have my currentSlide index to react dynamically?
Here is my code 
Php :

```
foreach($page_children as $page_children):
//Get Thumbnails ID from children pages
$children_thumbnail_ID= get_post_thumbnail_id($page_children);
//Get Thumbnail source
$children_thumbnail_image=wp_get_attachment_image_src($children_thumbnail_ID,'thumbnail');?>
<img class="thumbs" src="<?php ech0 $children_thumbnail_image[0];>"onclick="currentSlide(1)">
<?php endforeach; 
  };
```

Javascript

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
thumbs[i].className = thumbs[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
thumbs[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

I hope it is not too confusing, and thank you for your help, I would really appreciate it! Or maybe is there another method to do that? Basically I am not using a plugin because I need my thumbnails to be on my header section while my slideshow content is in the body. Also I am using the featured image of the children pages to be displayed in the slideshow on the parent page. Is there a better way to do that? I am very new to wordpress, php and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

it is simple . 
the only thing you have to do is add an integer in your loop. here is code that I changed for you.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ( $page_children as $page_children ):
//Get Thumbnails ID from children pages
    $i ++; // we increase it in the loop and print it on html.
    $children_thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_children );
//Get Thumbnail source
    $children_thumbnail_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $children_thumbnail_ID, 'thumbnail' );
    echo '<img class="thumbs" src="' . $children_thumbnail_image[0] . '" onClick="currentSlide(' . $i . ')" />';
endforeach;
```

Comment: thank you for having a look at my problem. Unfortunately, the code is still not working. When I click on the thumbnail, the console show me this error message:
(index):189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showSlides ((index):189)
    at currentSlide ((index):174)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):101)

Comment: is it online your website. 

can i have a look on your full js script and php?

Comment: as i see I think you checked first element. 

did you tried other elements for the first request?

Answer (score 0):

ok I made it work. I echoed the integer in my onClick and I placed the incrementation completely at the end of the loop, and it is working now!

```
$counter = 1;
    foreach($page_children as $children):
    <img class="thumbs" src="<?php echo $children_thumbnail_image[0];?>    
    "onclick="currentSlide(<?php echo $counter;?>)">
<?php $counter ++ ?>
<?php endforeach;
```

Thank you for your help!